# How to use A-Level Records to Point to different Services running on my Ubuntu Server on the Domain and Server side?

Tags: server, apache2, dns, webserver, nextcloud

I have a Ubuntu 20.04.5 Server with Nextcloud on it running just fine.
I used Apache2 and followed this [Tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nextcloud-ubuntu-20-04-apache-lamp-stack) to set it up as nextcloud.example.com.
On the Site where I bought the Domain I added an A-Level Record to point to the Domain of my Server. This works very well.
Now I am trying to install Collabora on my Server and integrate it with Nextcloud. Following this [Tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/integrate-collabora-onlinenextcloud-without-docker).
I have done all the Steps succesfully with no Error Messages.
Now I am confused about the A-Record. Does it just also Point to the Servers-IP?
What do I need to do on my Server so that this works.

Problems:
When I try to add the domain to Nextcloud Office, I get this:

```
Could not establish connection to the Collabora Online server
```

When I open the URL in my Browser, I get the Apache Default Page.

Can anyone point me in some Direction with this? Thanks.

Comment: If you get the default Apache page, then the virtual host and/or DNS record for the Collabora server isn't correctly configured - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the same stack as you - but on Docker. However, the principle about Collabora integrations and DNS records should be the same.

The DNS record for the Collabora should point to the same server (that is running the reverse proxy/virtual host).

In my case, I've also set up a reverse proxy and DNS records for both services (and the DNS records simply point to the server IP):

- `cloud.mydomain.com` (Nextcloud)
- `office.mydomain.com` (Collabora)

You can test that these are working by simply visiting the sites.

- Visiting `cloud.mydomain.com` will of course take you to the Nextcloud login page
- Visiting `office.mydomain.com` should take you to a blank white page saying `OK` in the top corner

If you don't get the white `OK` page for Collabora, then the reverse proxy and DNS aren't correctly set up.

To troubleshoot further, try to visit the IP address and port of the Collabora server (`http://your.ip.add.ress:9980`):

- If you get the `OK`, then Collabora is running, but the reverse proxy/virtual host isn't configured.
- If you *don't* get the `OK`, then the Collabora server itself isn't running properly.

Finally, when the above is confirmed, you can add the Collabora server to Nextcloud in "Settings", under "Office" and "Use your own server".